# Is it possible to connect to public Ethereum like blockchain with Remix to deploy and view contracts?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, rpc

I've tried to do so by specifying the web3 provider and the 8584 port but it gets stuck on every try.

Is this possible? if so, is there another solution for that need?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to one of the testnets using Metamask. You can find a lot of tutorials on the web explaining this. [Install](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en) metamask and [create](https://ddex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004413273-Create-a-new-MetaMask-account) a new account using it. [Get](https://faucet.ropsten.be/) some test ethers from Ropsten faucet. Go to Remix and select Injected web3 as your environment. Change network to Ropsten in Metamask. Then deploy.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your answer, in the link they explain how to connect to Ganache which is a local solution to simulate private blockchains, I'm trying to connect to a running, public, ETH like blockchain.

Comment: I've removed the tutorial link. Please try the steps in my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Deploy contracts

To deploy contracts do the following:

- Install MetaMask
- In MetaMask: select Main Ethereum Network or one of the test networks
- Make sure you have some ETH in your account (either by buying it or getting it via a faucet for the test networks)
- In Remix, via the plugin manager: add "Solidity compiler" and "Deploy & run transactions"
- Select "file explorer" and select a file, for example ballot.sol
- Select Solidity compiler and click "compile"
- Select Deploy & run transactions
- Select "Injected Web3" in the Environment dropdown
- Click Deploy

Now you can interact with the contract.

## View contracts

To see contacts do the following:

- Install MetaMask
- In MetaMask: select Main Ethereum Network
- Find a contract on etherscan with source code, for example:
  https://etherscan.io/address/0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca#code
- Check out the compiler version, e.g.: v0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9
- In Remix, via the plugin manager: add "Solidity compiler" and "Deploy & run transactions"
- In file manager: create a new file (+).
- Copy & Paste the source code of the contract from etherscan to remix
- Select Solidity compiler and select the appropriate compiler version (v0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9)
- Click "compile"
- Select Deploy & run transactions
- Select "Injected Web3" in the Environment dropdown
- Paste the address of the contact (e.g. 0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca) in the "At Address" field

Now you can interact with the contract.
You can select other interfaces in the dropdown box in the middle and press "At Address" again.